# How to attach a fragments inside an recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I want to include multiple fragments inside an recycler view.
I am having main categories which i want to show vertically and below each category i want its sub categories to be shown horizontally.

So, how should I do this as all the data is external.

I want a view something like this:

[image]

Comment: need to show your code here

Answer (score 0):

According to what i understood from your post, It would be better to show something like expand and collapse card views in recycler view with header as main category and its sub categories as collapsing part instead of adding multiple fragments

Comment: I have attached an screenshot for the reference of the view in the question.

Comment: this can be achieved with the expand and collapse card view as well. I have an example where i have tried using animation. but not sure how i can share the source file with u

Answer (score 0):

as per your screen shot , you can make one item containing two rows in which first row is "cloud", then second row is having three columns with details and then set it inside adapter. now you will be able to create multiple catogeries without using fragments. For Recyclerview demo follow the link below.

[Recyclerview link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)